# MS Word: can't remove excess empty space in table

Tags: ms-word, formatting, ms-office

I tried everything to remove the yellow-indicated whitespace in my MS Word invoice template. Somehow the table is longer (as seen by the grey box on the right side) as it should be - but in neither of the table properties can I find a clue on how to remove it. Also I obviously tried removing whatever is in this whitespace - no luck.

[image]

Comment: Did you check the row-height in the table properties > row (first row selected). De-select "define height" (Höhe definieren).

Comment: yeah tried that.. just went on to rebuild it - this was from standard word invoice template. Now with the 10 min rebuild it works much cleaner. thanks for the help though

Comment: Your question is off-topic here. Stack Overflow is for questions about programming. Please post your query at http://answers.microsoft.com or Super User.